# TransactionSystemException in Long running Spring Batch Jobs

Tags: spring-batch, jobs, rollback

I have a Spring Batch Job which are sometimes running longer than 2700 seconds.  When they do, I am noticing an exception that is coming from the spring batch framework.

SpringFramework versions:

```
<spring-batch.version>2.2.7.RELEASE</spring-batch.version>
<spring.framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
```

Here is the definition of the job:

```
<batch:job id="MyJob">
    <batch:step id="trigger-job" next="poll-job">
        <batch:tasklet ref="triggerJobStep" />
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="phaseStepListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="poll-job">
        <batch:tasklet ref="pollJobStatusStep" />
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="phaseStepListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="phaseCompletionListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

Seems like the connection to the database is running out.

This issue always happens while I am polling a service which is taking a long time.

If there are any recommendations or other approaches, please let me know!

Also note, that for jobs which do not run very long < 2700 seconds, there are NO problems.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Dave

Stack traces of the job:

```
"errorMessage":"Step requested termination: StepExecution: id=15365, version=2, name=poll-cmpaas-deploy, status=UNKNOWN, exitStatus=FAILED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=1, 
exitDescription=org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:546)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:849)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:826)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.rollbackOnException(TransactionTemplate.java:164)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:141)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:151)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:111)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:542)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:108)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:211)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:5101)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.rollback(NewProxyConnection.java:860)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:163)
    ... 23 more
Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking","warningMessage":null,"data":null}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database connection is being severed after 45 minutes.  Either your server is killing it, or (more likely) you have a firewall between your app and the database that is killing persistent connections that are that open long (firewalls typically will cut persistent connections, regardless if they are in use after a certain period of time).  Assuming it is a firewall, you'll need to get that configured to not cut your connection.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I figured that there was an issue with the database connection dropping.  Here is my problem.  In my job, I am not using the database as all.  It appears that SpringBatch is having the issue.  So how do other people handle jobs that potentially run for 10-14 hours?  Is there another strategy I can use?  In my job, I have a step which is monitoring another process.  This step has a while loop with a sleep.  When this other process completes, the job exits.  Thanks for any input or suggestions.

Comment: I found the issue.  Inside my step, I had a loop which was waiting for the job to finish.  SpringBatch apparently does not like this if the time exceeds a certain long period of time like 40+ minutes.  The solution was to return RepeatStatus.CONTINUABLE and get called again.